# How do I read in a file from ansible and get it to return the last few lines?

Tags: while-loop, ansible

I have a log file that updates over time. After it updates there is a specific line in the log that specifies that the update is complete, near the end of the file. I want to create a task using Ansible that reads in this file and returns the last line of the file, or at least the last few lines. If the line isn't found re read the file (as it means it is still updating). Does anyone know how I can go about this?

I've tried looking at documentation and have made a task that at reads the log file into a variable but I'm not sure where to go from here, or even if this is the right way to do it? Below is what I've done so far. I'm working on a windows machine.

```
- name: Check Log file
    win_shell: cmd /k TYPE C:\Files\logfile.log
    register: logFile
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: just to understand your question correctly, do you want this task to continuosly (loop for infinite) keep reading the file until it file the said regex? or do you have a cron or something which run this ansible after frequent interval?

Comment: also can you upload a portion of the log file?

Comment: @garlicFrancium Yes I would like it to loop infinitely - I've looked at implementing the "until" loop in Ansible. I'm unable to upload a portion of the log file, but it would contain something along the lines of "registering Mbean....". I also need to only exit the loop when such a line appears in the last line of the log file. So I know which line to look in, and what to look for, but not how to tell Ansible to look for this.

Comment: when check "registering Mbean...." do you want to check each and every line in the log file or just the last line?

Comment: @garlicFrancium just the last line

Comment: You probably want to have a look a the [`wait_for`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/wait_for_module.html) module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we can use a module called [lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html) although the module is used for a different purpose but it can be used in conjuction to

- `check_mode: yes` which ensure it will not write anything to file ever
- `until: not presence.changed` will do the required looping for you
- `retries: 5` this is the number of retries, therefore for infinite loop set it to a large number but absolute infinity is not encouraged here!

  `- name: find
       lineinfile:
         path: /PATH/TO/LOG_FILE
         line: 'registering Mbean....'
       check_mode: yes
       register: presence
       until: not presence.changed
       retries: 5
       delay: 10`

UPDATE: @zeitounator suggestion in comments of the question looks cleaner and is implemented below

`- name: WAIT
  wait_for:
    path: /PATH/TO/LOG_FILE
    search_regex: 'registering Mbean....'`